# Exception when listing created sub-directory in documents directory

Tags: file-io, io, dart, directory, flutter

I am using the official API to list a directory I had created for some purpose and have pushed few files into it. Now I want to list them out.

Here's how I am creating first

```
final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
//    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Movies/flutter_test';
final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/mydir';
await new Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
```

Here's what I am doing to read in a different page.

```
final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
//    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/flutter_test';
final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/mydir';
final String thumbDirPath = '$dirPath/thumbs';
final Directory imgDir = Directory.fromUri(Uri.file(dirPath));

dirExists = imgDir.existsSync();
fileCount = 0;
if(dirExists) {
  print("my dir exists");

//      thumbDir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
  fileCount = await imgDir.list(recursive: false).length;
  print('mydir images count $fileCount');
  if(fileCount > 1) { // we think one is always the directory itself?
    try {
      imgDir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
          .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
```

The code breaks here giving the following exception message

```
type '() => Null' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => FutureOr<dynamic>'
```

I have to also tell you this doesn't happen when I am listing the external storage directory. Am I doing something wrong while creating my directory?

EDIT

I have now upgraded flutter to 0.7.3 on my Mac, and have a new problem altogether. The application won't run at all.

Comment: At what line you are getting this error

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian I mentioned where it is breaking.

Comment: What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer beta 0.5.1. on Mac osx 10.13.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution myself. Apparently tinkering with the large provider API has given me different way to list the items, which actually told me I was trying to run listeners twice.

```
fileCount = await imgDir.list(recursive: false).length;
```

and

```
imgDir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false)
      .listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
```

from original code cannot be written one after the other, as the first one finishes the listener. This I found out by altering my own code and listing directories this way instead.

```
Stream<FileSystemEntity> files = imgDir.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false);
```

will add as many events as many files according to API.. and then create a regular generic list

```
List<FileSystemEntity> entities = await files.toList();
```

and then you perform usual iteration using iterator or for() loop like

```
for(FileSystemEntity entity in entities) {
... // every file now is available
```